# How to get the data back of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

Question:

I would like to get the information in the JTable back into an Array of String[][] 2-dimensional array when the save button is pressed. Actually I would like to update a new String[][] array every time a key is pressed but that will have to wait until the Save button is working.

When I made my ActionListener I had to create another instance of TestTable so I could pass in the table since I like to make all of my ActionListeners outside of the main class.

Action Listener:

```
            class buttonListener implements ActionListener {
        private String[][] tempTable = null; 
        **TestTable tt = new TestTable();**

        public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
          int nRow = table.getRowCount();
          int nCol = table.getColumnCount();
          String[][] tData = new String[nRow][nCol];

          for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++) {
              tData[i][j] = (String) table.getValueAt(i,j);
            }
          }
            return tData;
        }

        **@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           tempTable = (String[][]) getTableData(tt.t);
        }**
    }
```

This is the code for the simple JTable.

**Question: I want to be able to save the data when the button is clicked?**

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class TestTable extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      String[] columnNames = {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7"};
      Object[][] data = {
            {"A", "B", "C", new Integer(1), new Boolean(true), "AA", "BB"},
            {"D", "E", "F", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false), "CC", "DD"},
            {"G", "H", "I", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true), "EE", "FF"},
            {"J", "K", "L", new Integer(4), new Boolean(false), "GG", "HH"},
            {"M", "N", "O", new Integer(5), new Boolean(true), "II", "JJ"}
      };
      JTable t;

    public TestTable() {
        t = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        t.addMouseListener( new mouseListener());
        t.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(t);
        add(scrollPane);
        //add(t);
    }

    private void OpenGUI() {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Save JTable");
        b1.addActionListener(new buttonListener());
        b1.setBounds(0,0,150,150);

        TestTable n = new TestTable();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("...Test JTable...");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(n);
        f.add(b1);
        //f.add(n);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
        int nRow = table.getRowCount();
        int nCol = table.getColumnCount();

        String[][] tData = new String[nRow][nCol];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++) {
                tData[i][j] = (String) table.getValueAt(i,j);
            }
        }

        return tData;
    }

    private void printData(Object[][] d, String[] s) {
        for (int c=0;c<d.length;c++) {
            System.out.println("Column Name: " + s[c]);
            for (int r=0;r<d.length;r++) {
                System.out.print(d[c][r] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] MeatBalls) {
        TestTable myClass = new TestTable();
        buttonListener l  = new buttonListener();
        myClass.OpenGUI();
        myClass.printData(myClass.data,myClass.columnNames);
        myClass.data = myClass.getTableData(myClass.t);
        myClass.printData(myClass.data,myClass.columnNames);
    }
}

class buttonListener implements ActionListener {
    private String[][] tempTable = null; 
    TestTable tt = new TestTable();

    public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
      int nRow = table.getRowCount();
      int nCol = table.getColumnCount();
      String[][] tData = new String[nRow][nCol];

      for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++) {
          tData[i][j] = (String) table.getValueAt(i,j);
        }
      }
        return tData;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       tempTable = (String[][]) getTableData(tt.t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to simplify this code (and follow Java conventions):

1. Make the `JTable` that holds the data and is displayed an instance variable. Do **not** create a new `JTable`. Inner classes can access *any* of the outer class's variables, so you can (and should) have the instance variable be private.
2. Get rid of the `getTableData` method in the outer class. You won't be needing that.
3. Have the `getTableData` method return `String[][]` instead of `Object[][]`. You're using `String[][]` inside the method, and you aren't doing anyone favors by returning an `Object[][]`.
4. When the `actionPerformed` method is triggered, use the `getTableData` method in the inner class to get the data in the `JTable` through the instance variable in the outer class.
5. Use proper casing for class names and method names. Method names begin with a lower case, while class names begin with an upper case. You can see how StackOverflow thinks `OpenGUI` is a class. Make your instance variables private if nothing outside of this class is using them (and if it's not a constant). Also, watch the indentation.